# Php: append extension to all files with no extension in a folder

Tags: php, append

I have a folder called `MyFolder` with these three files:

`file1
file2
file3.gif
file.html`

I need to add the extension '.gif' to the files with no extension. Then the first `file1` and second `file2` files should be targeted.

Result should be:

`file1.gif
file2.gif
file3.gif
file.html`

**The files are gif files, but somehow they lost the extensions. If I add the extension manually (editing its names) then I can load correctly in the browser**

I'm trying with this code:

```
$directory = "http://www.example.com/MyFolder/";
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) { 
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {   

        if($fileName['extension'] == ""){

            $fileName = $fileName.".gif";
        }
        rename($directory . $fileName, $directory . $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: seems easy enough - what code is causing issues?

Comment: Note: that won't actually make them gifs of course, if they aren't already (seems obvious, I know, but it might be worth noting).

Comment: @RamRaider I added the code I tried to use.

Comment: @CD001 The files are gif files, but somehow they lost the extensions. If I add the extension manually (editing its names) then I can load correctly in the browser.

Comment: @JPashs - just making sure ;) Personally I'd [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately because you can't pass `preg_grep` into `array_walk` this had to be split like so, otherwise it could have been a single line.

```
$dir='./MyFolder/';
$col=preg_grep( '@^((?!gif).)*$@i', glob( $dir . '*' ) );

array_walk( $col , function($f){
    rename( $f, $f.'.gif' );
});
```

Or, a modified version of the original

```
if( $handle = opendir( $directory ) ) { 
    while( false !== $filename = readdir( $handle ) ) {
        if( !is_dir( $filename ) ) {
            $file = $directory . $filename;
            if( empty( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ) ){
                rename( $file, $file . '.gif' );
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

As the original above happily renamed files with extensions other than gif a more simple version without the faulty regex seems to work OK.

```
$dir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';
$col=glob( $dir . '*' );

array_walk( $col, function( $f ){
    if( empty( pathinfo( $f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ) ){
        printf('%s - %s<br />',$f,$f.'.gif');
        rename( $f, $f.'.gif' );
    }
});
```

Comment: I works but the function adds the '.gif' to all files, even if they have an extension. Then, 'file.xml' get rename to 'file.xml.gif'.  I need to only add '.gif' to files with name with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rename to add the `.gif` extension after you've detected that it is missing. Your current code was using a variable `$newname` that didn't exist.

```
while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {   

        if($fileName['extension'] == ""){
           rename($directory . $fileName, $directory . $fileName . '.gif');
        }
}
```